# powershell : xcopy directory template acl to a new folder

Tags: powershell, xcopy

I'm trying to do an xcopy /o equivalent to copy a template folder with subdirectories which contain their own appropriate acl to create a new target directory with the same subdirectories and their respective acl in a windows 2008 server environment.

for example..

```
the template directory would be  templatedir
- sql 
- pm 
- dev 

targetdir  
- sql 
- pm 
- dev
```

with each subdir having the same acl

here is what i have come up with so far

```
PS C:\> dir c:\templatefolder -recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer} | foreach { 
$target= ($_.fullname).replace("C:\templatefolder","D:\targetfolder") 
  Get-Acl $_.Fullname | Set-Acl $target -whatif 
}
```

how do i modify this so it includes the inheritance and copies the templatedir's acl?  it currently only does the subfolders.  thanks in advance

Comment: robocopy?  (In particular, see the /copy option where you can specify which attributes will be copied.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem` so it will return all the "child" items in the template dir but not the dir itself.  To copy the ACLs for the template dir add this command e.g.:

```
PS C:\> Get-Acl C:\templatefolder | Set-Acl -path D:\targetfolder -whatif
```

As for setting up inheritance, this would be much easier using `icacls.exe`:

```
C:\PS> icacls <name> /inheritance:e
```

Run `icacls /?` to see help on this Windows utility.